# How can I tell if 2 fragments have an instance from the same class

Tags: android, class, instance, fragment

Let's say that I have a fragment inside a container that I should replace with an other fragment.

The code is quite simple:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().
replace(R.id.content_frame,fragmentToAdd).addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

The problem is now that I want to make sure that fragmentToAdd is not similar to the fragment I will replace.

If this is the case, the app should do nothing.

So, I can get the original Fragment:

```
Fragment originalFragment=(Fragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.content_frame);
```

and the final code would be something like:

```
if (haveDifferentInstance(originalFragment,fragmentToAdd)){
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().
    replace(R.id.content_frame,fragmentToAdd).addToBackStack(null).commit();}
else
    // Do nothing
```

So, what could be the code for haveDifferentInstance(Fragment fragmentA, Fragment fragmentB)?

Thank for any help.

**EDIT**

I know that I can do somethinh like:

```
if (fragmentToAdd instanceof FragmentA)
```

But has I have FragmentA, FragmentB, .... Fragment F, I don't want to use a 'if' per type of Fragment.

Comment: Why not set the `Tag` parameter when adding a `Fragment` and then use `findFragmentByTag(String tag)`?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Check if the class are equal : `if(origianalFragment.getClass().equals(fragmentToAdd.getClass()))`

Answer (score 0):

You can check the simplename.

```
if (fragmentToAdd.class.getSimpleName().equals(originalFragment.getClass().getSimpleName()))
{
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In kotlin, instanceOf substitute is "is" operator.
if (fragmentToAdd instanceof FragmentA) will be written as in kotlin like

**if (fragmentToAdd is FragmentA) {..}**